# Process running when starting terminal on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

Whenever I start terminal on my Macbook Pro it is running a process. I have to use ctrl+C to kill it. If I close the window directly it warns me that following processs are running: login, bash, bash, perl5.12.

Any idea what might be going on here and how I get back to the normal state?

Comment: I guess you have added something in your bash profile... try looking in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

I personally had this issue a while ago. First check to see if it is from one of your profiles. Assuming you are using bash, we will look at your bash profile.

First, make sure the problem is actually stemming from your bash profile. Source the scrips as follows.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.profile
```

If after running those you observe the same hanging problem where you have to cntrl+c, then you know what script has the problem.

The best way to remedy the situation is to comment out different parts of your script to figure out where the problem is. Backup your profile and then comment out half of your profile and do a

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and if it hangs or not will tell you what half the problem is on. Keep repeating this until you find the problem. It sounds longer than it actually is.